# Visual Studio 2019 and 2022, cannot add new web.config, missing 'add config transform' option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I want to create a new config file that should be used on the new Configuration i made.
But seems the option is missing when i right click most of the things out of google and say "right click on web.config and click on 'add config transform', but the thing is, that option is not available in VS2019 and VS2022".

[image]

So what are my options, how do i add a new web.config file?

From the screenshot above, i see that the old developer already created one, but he already left so i have nothing to ask.

Comment: I can reproduce this when I don't have any additional configurations that don't have a transform already, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037072/asp-net-web-application-add-config-transform-grayed-out) says.  So, are you positive your configuration has been created and saved?